# including css in Twig

Tags: php, html, twig

I am pretty new to the template engine itself. I am wondering how I could include my css stylesheet using twig as it doesn't render the styles everytime I render it.

**index.html** including the css stylesheet.

```
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="icomoon/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

**index.html** showing the data (the data is shown correctly, just the css stylesheet, isn't rendering (or the design is not shown).

```
{% if sv_query.connect and sv_data.password == 0 %}
    <center><img src="images/status/server-online.png"/><br/>Server is online!</center>
    <center>Players: <font color=green><b>{{ sv_data.players }}</b></center>
{% elseif sv_data.password == 1 %}
    <center><img src="images/status/server-warning.png"></br>The server is passworded (under construction).</center>
{% else %}
    <center><img src="images/status/server-offline.png"></br>The server is offline, try again later!</center>
{% endif %}
```

A basic example of how I render the data. **Index.php** (twig)

```
require 'Twig/vendor/autoload.php';

$loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem('views');
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);

$ip = "127.0.0.1";
$port = "7777";

require("views/samp/samp_query.php");

$query = new SampQuery($ip, $port); 
$info = $query->GetInfo();

echo $twig->render('index.html', array (
    'sv_query' => $query,
    'sv_data' => $info)
);
$query->close();
```

**PS** I am not using any plugins or templates engines other than **twig** as what I am doing right now is pretty basic, I just need to get the stylesheet to function properly, or to be included properly.

Thanks, Patrick!

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "it doesn't render the styles"? Are you saying that when you view the source of the page, you do not see your `link` lines? Or are they there and the styles from those files just aren't being applied? Have you checked your developer console network tab to see if requests are being made for those files and if so, what the response is?

Comment: well if I just open the .html page it self, everything is normal.

This is what I meant. https://i.imgur.com/mUPkY2M.png even tho should look something like this https://imgur.com/a/Ul8Hw (ignore the twig codes on the right) @PatrickQ

Comment: Be careful with relative URL's. What is the url you are trying to access and where is your CSS stored?

Comment: So, are the .css files loaded at all? Checked your browser's devconsole/network tab or the source?

Comment: You didn't really answer the questions that I asked.

Comment: @DarkBee oh thanks for reminding me that! I thought it out just read it from the .html file not from the .php file, I have sorted it out :)